# Flickering in a Windows C# dev express

Tags: c#, devexpress-windows-ui

I have an Dev Express Windows Form Application and it has a massive amount of flicker, particularly on startup.

I applied this fix to it.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED

        return cp;
    }
}
```

This code fix the flickering problem but it used 30-50 CPU Usages.

How to Fix this problem ?

Comment: What in the world is a `30-50 CPU Usages`?

Comment: Thanks,It means exe file uses 30-50 % CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting DoubleBuffered = true for the Form? I am not sure it will work with DevExpress or not. You can find an MSDN topic for the same  - [How to: Reduce Graphics Flicker with Double Buffering for Forms and Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on what type of controls are on the form.  DevExpress has many controls that have a `.SuspendLayout()` and `.ResumeLayout()` which prevent flickering and hang-ups while the specific control is being loaded.